# getting 2-3 popups while running cordova app given in description and then browser stucks

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, angular, phonegap-build

```
gap_init:2 
gap:[null,"CoreAndroid","messageChannel","CoreAndroid1594682113"] 
gap:[null,"CoreAndroid","show","CoreAndroid1594682114"]
```

I am trying to develop Cordova app with `angular js 2.0` 
I have created `Cordova` hello world and angular js 2.0 hello world then I have merged both the things

But while running the app these `popups` are generated and then nothing happens

Comment: How you are running your code? Using serve command?

Comment: using command NPM START as I am using visual studio code terminal

Comment: Have you tested in real device? Do you still get the issue?

Comment: I didn't try with a real device because I am not able to make a build even.

Answer (score 1):

You make project using angular-cli, You make one cordova project Then in your angular-cli.json file -> change the path to cordova's www folder.

Then when you do ng prod build, your resources would be copied to cordova's www folder.

I wrote one cordova hook for the same,

```
const fs = require('fs');
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;



module.exports = function(context) {
    const basePath = context.opts.projectRoot;
    const baseWWW = basePath + '/www';

process.chdir('../bmi-surgical-app');
console.log(`New directory: ${process.cwd()}`);

    execSync("ng build --prod --base-href .",{stdio:[0,1,2]});

    var files = fs.readdirSync(baseWWW);
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      if (files[i].endsWith('.gz')) {
        fs.unlinkSync(baseWWW + '/' + files[i]);
      }
    }
    fs.writeFileSync(baseWWW + '/.gitignore', `# Ignore everything in this directory

*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
`);


};
```

However many better options are available like NativeScript & Ionic 2.

Comment: Actually, I am new to PhoneGap or Cordova so I don't know what is the use of hook and how can I use it as we tried for beta angular 2.0 with ios and it's working perfectly. so we need to do same as IOS

Comment: hook is something which u want to execute before cordova build or cordova run command. 

The above hook does the following purpose
Generated minified, transpiled files in the www folder. ignores the compressed gz files of Angular CLI.